# Vue 3 refs is undefined in render function

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a simple Vue component with root element as `ref="divRef"`. However, in `onMounted` function, `divRef.value` returns undefined. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref, Ref, h } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
    setup(props, context) {
        const divRef = ref() as Ref<HTMLElement>

        onMounted(() => {
            console.log(divRef.value) // undefined
        })

        return () => {
            return h(
                "div",
                {
                    ref: "divRef"
                },
                "This is a div"
            )
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `render` function, pass the `divRef` itself, not a string:

```js
return h(
    "div",
    {
        //ref: "divRef"   // DON'T DO THIS
        ref: divRef
    },
    "This is a div"
)
```

Answer (score 5):

`div` elements do not have `value` attribute by default if you are trying to access `"This is a div"` *(text within the `div`)* you should use [`innerText`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwidruLPmcPqAhWqmeAKHQ3UDLUQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FHTMLElement%2FinnerText&usg=AOvVaw0zB7bhk8aydt_ETy3wAwxU) property like this: `divRef.innerText`.

### Update

According to [docs](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#template-refs), you have to pass the ref itself as the ref in your return element to get access to `$el` in Vue 3. So your code should be something like this:

```js
return () => {
  return h(
    "div", {
      ref: divRef
    },
    "This is a div"
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are use jsx in render function. you also need pass the `divRef` itself, can't by string.

```
set() {
  const divRef = ref() as Ref<HTMLElement>

  return () => <div ref={divRef}></div>
}
```